# Symfony2 auth denied and getToken()->getRoles() different from getToken()->getUser()->getRoles()

Tags: symfony

I'm using FOSUserBundle to manager users, now I'm trying to secure some controller actions with JMS\SecurityExtraBundle. I have set `ROLE_SUPER_USER` on my user and protected a method with `@Secure(roles="SUPER_ADMIN")` but I am not allawed to call the method.

After a LOT of digging up into the code of Symfony2 I think I have traced the issue to the fact that `getToken()->getRoles()` only returns `ROLE_USER` whereas `getToken()->getUser()->getRoles()` correctly returns the user roles, including `ROLE_SUPER_USER`.

So what could be happening there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAHA

I was missing the lines :

```
providers:
            main:
                entity: { class: FM\SymSlateBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```

in security.yml :

```
security:
    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: FM\SymSlateBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```

Thus the Context was using the default user class which only has USER_ROLE